# Automatic Package Restore with Nuget, custom package sources, and duplicate package names/versions

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, nuget

We have trying to move all the fetching of our dependencies into Nuget.  We use our own custom package source, as well as the default nuget.org source.  We have custom packages that happen to have the same name/version # of packages that exist on nuget.org.

So, in VS2013 and VS2015, I've update the package manager settings to have the two package sources (custom then nuget.org) and enabled the nuget 2.7+ automatic package restore.  I also added a nuget.config file in the root of our solution that contains the package sources:

```
<!-- nuget.config -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositorypath" value="c:\nuget\packages" />
  </config>
  <packagesources>
    <add key="customsource" value="http://custom.url/nuget" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packagesources>
</configuration>
```

I've run into a situation where when I rebuild the solution in VS2013 on my box, it pulls down all packages with duplicate names/versions from the custom source fine.  But if we rebuild the solution on another person's machine, it appears to ignore the custom source and try and pull everything from nuget.org, regardless if the setting are the same on their machine.

When I try and rebuild the solution in VS2015, it seems to ignore the custom source and pulls any packages that have duplicate names/versions from nuget.org.

If I use nuget.exe 2.8.2 on the command line, everything works as expected and packages are pulled fine as long as I keep the custom source as first in the list.  If I use nuget.exe 3.3.0 on the command line, I have to have the custom source as last in my source list to pull my duplicate packages from my custom source.  If the custom source is first in the list, nuget 3.3.0 just restores all duplicate packages from nuget.org.

In my testing, I cleared all nuget caches before trying any restore.

Has anyone run into this issue, and if so, how did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I seem to have fixed the issue.  First, I modified the nuget.config file located in the root of my solution to the following:

```
<!-- nuget.config -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositorypath" value="c:\nuget\packages" />
  </config>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packagesources>
    <add key="customsource" value="http://custom.url/nuget" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packagesources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Next, I found another nuget.config located under C:\Users\ExitusLSU\AppData\Roaming\Nuget that looked like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packagesources>
    <add key="customsource" value="http://custom.url/nuget" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packagesources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

It appears that Visual Studio, when initiating the nuget package restore was reading from this file and ignoring the nuget.config file located in the solution.  I noticed whenever I tried reordering the package sources within Visual Studio, the source order never got updated in the solution nuget.config file.  I deleted the "roaming" nuget.config file and restarted Visual Studio.  The "roaming" nuget.config got recreated, but with basically nothing in the file.  Now, the solution nuget.config was getting updated properly and my package sources were being read properly.

Thanks to all for taking the time to answer my question and provide some help!

Answer (score 1):

In the short term, try opening the package manager console, selecting the appropriate package source, and then restoring the packages.

[image: Package Manager Console Snapshot]

In the longer term, try prefixing the packages in your internal feed with some sort of qualifier.  For instance, instead of `package`, do `<your company name>.package`.  This should resolve your package naming issues.

Another thing that's generally a good idea is to check in your packages into source control.  That way, any developer getting latest has as little configuration as possible to get right in order to build the code.  More on this philosophy is available on [many](https://www.jayway.com/2015/03/27/check-in-your-nuget-packages/) [blog](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/29/nuget-package-restore-considered-harmful/) [posts](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/05/10-commandments-of-good-source-control.html#10.-Dependencies-need-a-home-too).  Basically, the model is, if you need it to build your code then **check it in**.  Then, you'll only have to worry about updating the package from the right feed, instead of relying on every developer knowing which feed to download the project from.